# There is a problem about numpy.loadtxt() convert string to float that confusion me very much

Tags: python, numpy

**Code:**

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
from sklearn import model_selection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import colors

def iris_type(s):
    class_label={b'Iris-setosa':0,b'Iris-versicolor':1,b'Iris-virginica':2}
    return class_label[s]

filepath='E:\dataset\IRIS\IRIS.csv'  # the path of dataset 
data=np.loadtxt(filepath,dtype=float,delimiter=',',converters={4:iris_type})
```

When I try to transform species of IRIS, the returned error is:
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDRY9.png)

The data-set I use is downloaded from kaggle.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NqNR.png)

I'd like to format species to a float.

Comment: The error says it can't convert the string `sepal length` to a float.  That looks like a header string.  Your `loadtxt` command doesn't do anything about headers.  For a start you might want to load this dataset with `dtype=None` and `names=True`, getting a structured array.

Comment: At first,Thanks for you answer my question.I try the methods that you provide,but  the error is still.   If i don't use the command load dataset,what i should use to ?

Comment: Thanks, i have solve this question to set a parameter skiprows=1.